# Executor multithread doesnt work

Tags: callbacks, multi-thread, multithreading, callbackqueue

Im having problems to execute tasks from 2 nodes using the multithreadExecutors and the call_back groups.

I'm running 1 node with 2 classes:

```
class MoveSubscriber(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("subs_node")
        self.group = ReentrantCallbackGroup()
        self.create_subscription(Odometry, '/odometry/local',self.update_pose,1,callback_group=self.group)
        self.create_timer(0.05,self.timer_callback,callback_group=self.group)
        self.pose=Pose2D()
```

Where that subscription to Odometry update self.pose. Until here, all works ok.

Then my second class:

```
class MovePublisher(Node):

def __init__(self):
    super().__init__("pub_node")
    self.velocity_publisher = self.create_publisher(Twist, '/cmd_vel',10)
    self.move2goal()


def move2goal(self):
        goal_pose = Pose2D()
        # Get the input from the user.
        point_x, point_y = input("input from user  (x,y): ").split(",")
        goal_pose.x = 1.0#float(point_x)
        goal_pose.y = 1.0#float(point_y)
....more stuff to calculate the goal
        while  abs(self.steering_angle(goal_pose) - self.pose.theta) >= angle_tolerance:
                ##rotate and other things
```

And lastly, def from the node:

```
def main(args=None):
rclpy.init(args=args)

try:
    subs_node = MoveSubscriber()
    pub_node = MovePublisher()
    executor = MultiThreadedExecutor(num_threads=30)
    executor.add_node(subs_node)
    executor.add_node(pub_node)
    try:
        executor.spin()
    finally:
        executor.shutdown()
        subs_node.destroy_node()
        pub_node.destroy_node()
finally:
      rclpy.shutdown()
```

As you can imagine, "waiting for input from user" and "while loop" will stop the class MoveSubscriber from receiving the odom messages being published. That's the idea for the executors. Nevertheless, with this configuration, it stops receiving and updating the "pose".

Any idea?

Of course I tested taking out "input from user", changing thread numbers and taking out callback-groups

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you provide us with a log of what happens when you execute your program? That will help us understand your problem better

Comment: Hello Ssarkar. I've just fix it reorganizing the node in order to take out the while section. If I do it like that the executors work ok. But as soon I put a while on any of the nodes, it just stops the other one.